# Apache Log rotation Script

Tags: apache, scripting, rotation, logging

I have the following script running to backup my apache logs

```
#!/bin/sh
dt=`date +%m%d%Y`
cp /var/log/httpd/domainname/www/error_log /var/log/httpd/domainname/www/oldlogs/error_log$dt
cat /dev/null > /var/log/httpd/domainname/www/error_log
cp /var/log/httpd/domainname/www/access_log /var/log/httpd/domainname/www/oldlogs/access_log$dt
cat /dev/null > /var/log/httpd/domainname/www/access_log
```

Which is scheduled via cron. So each night the logs get backed up and emptied. However, the next morning I always get files with weird characters after the date

```
[me@computer oldlogs]# ls
access_log07202009??  access_log07212009??  error_log07202009??  error_log07212009??

[me@computer oldlogs]#cat access_log072
access_log07202009^M^Maccess_log07212009^M^M
```

and I'm unable to find what is causing it. Any idea?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this *doesn't* belong on serverfault. Shell scripts are programming, plain and simple.

Comment: I actually started filing this bug at serverfault but decided to file it here for the reason you stated Pax. Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) is your friend

Comment: Didn't know about logroate; Wonderful and I no longer have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be checking:

- the `${dt}` variable from within the cron job (`echo "${dt}" | od -xcb >/tmp/qq`); and
- the actual script itself (`od -xcb scriptname`);

to see if there's weird characters being generated anywhere.

Also, I can't figure out your second command. Is there an `access_log072` file there somewhere or was your command truncated somehow?